# excel vba userform/button coding

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have created a workbook in Excel. To navigate I have inserted a userform. I have code which takes me to a spreadsheet once a button is clicked on the userform.

Now I would like a button on the spread sheet which will close the current spread sheet and take the user back to the userform which is default to a sheet I've named "home". however I do not no the coding which will alow me to do this

Comment: I'm a little lost. You are saying you'd have to navigate to a different worksheet to close the worksheet you are (were) on?

Comment: effectively yes. all my sheets are hidden so the user just cannot simply select the worksheet they would like to go to, they need to click a button. The button will take them back to the worksheet which is associated with the user form.

Comment: OK, nearly there... So you want to be able to close WorksheetX and then show the worksheet named Home?

Comment: yes! id also like to open my user form which is name "Interface". sorry to be so vague in my description!.

Comment: When you say spreadsheet, do you mean worksheet or workbook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is confusing, probably because it is bespoke to your needs.

However, I read the question as "how to close a spreadsheet" to mean "how to close a worksheet"

You can't, you can only delete it or hide it. Depending on your set up, this may be OK

The code to delete a specific worksheet and then select a different worksheet is

```
Sub EeekPirates()
Application.DisplayAlerts = False   ' this stops the "are you sure message box"
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = True    ' put this back on since it's an application wide change
End Sub
```

And the code to hide it

```
Sub EeekPirates()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False
Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate
End Sub
```

Both have issues but as I said, there is no way of knowing your set up so hopefully this will be enough to get you going.